# Azure DevOps trigger at pipeline completion using different branch than expected

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the workflow of a pipeline triggering another pipeline according to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops), I'm trying to set:

1. feature-branch PR to develop-branch triggers stage-ci
2. stage-ci runs, triggers stage-cd
3. pipeline stage-cd runs

But in step 3, it gets the default branch, not the feature-branch.
Does anyone know why this is happening? When the trigger in stace-ci is `trigger` (not `pr`) it works fine

stage-ci.yaml:

```
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
```

stage-cd.yaml

```
trigger: none

pr: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: stage-ci
    source: stage-ci
    trigger: true
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines). `pr` only works for repositories hosted in GitHub or BitBucket. For PR triggers on Azure DevOps-hosted repositories, you should use a branch policy with a required pipeline run.

Comment: It's in bitbucket, and the pipeline is triggering... only with the wrong branch